# Cannot show the published path in rviz ROS

Tags: c++, ros

I am a newer to ROS and trying to publish a path in ROS. I have checked that the topic "/path" is published but the path seems not shown in rviz [I can select the /path and it seems work but no trajectory is shown. I am sure the line is not transparent]. I donn't know why? Very grateful if anyone could help me. Following are my codes:

BroadcastPath.cpp

"""

```
#include "control_turtle/BroadcastPath.hpp"

namespace broadcast_path {

BroadcastPath::BroadcastPath(ros::NodeHandle& nodeHandle)
    : nodeHandle_(nodeHandle)
{
    publisher_ = nodeHandle_.advertise<nav_msgs::Path>("/path",1);
    subscriber_ = nodeHandle_.subscribe("/odom", 2, &BroadcastPath::topicCallback, this);

}

BroadcastPath::~BroadcastPath()
{
}

void BroadcastPath::topicCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry& msg)
{
    nav_msgs::Path path;
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose;

    pose.pose.position = msg.pose.pose.position;
    pose.pose.orientation = msg.pose.pose.orientation;

    path.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    path.header.frame_id = "map";
    path.poses.push_back(pose);

    publisher_.publish(path);

}

} /* namespace */
```

"""

Broadcast_path_node.cpp

"""

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "control_turtle/BroadcastPath.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "broadcast_path");
  ros::NodeHandle nodeHandle("~");
  ros::Rate loopRate(10);

  broadcast_path::BroadcastPath broadcastPath(nodeHandle);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

"""

BroadcastPath.hpp

"""

```
#pragma once


// ROS
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>
#include <nav_msgs/Path.h>

namespace broadcast_path {

/*!
 * Main class for the node to handle the ROS interfacing.
 */
class BroadcastPath
{
 public:
  /*!
   * Constructor.
   * @param nodeHandle the ROS node handle.
   */
    BroadcastPath(ros::NodeHandle& nodeHandle);

  /*!
   * Destructor.
   */
  virtual ~BroadcastPath();

 private:

  /*!
   * ROS topic callback method.
   * @param message the received message.
   */
  void topicCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry& msg);


  /*!
   * ROS service server callback.
   * @param request the request of the service.
   * @param response the provided response.
   * @return true if successful, false otherwise.
   */

  //! ROS node handle.
  ros::NodeHandle& nodeHandle_;

  //! ROS publisher
  ros::Publisher publisher_;
  ros::Subscriber subscriber_;

  int count = 0;

};

} /* namespace */
```

"""

Answer (score 1):

In BroadcastPath.cpp, you should assign a header to the pose before pushing it to path.
You should also set the frame_id of the path to parentId("odom" if you are using the ros standard) and the set the frame_id of the pose to childId("base_link" if you are using the ros standard).
Your code should look like this:

```
#include "control_turtle/BroadcastPath.hpp"

namespace broadcast_path {

BroadcastPath::BroadcastPath(ros::NodeHandle& nodeHandle)
    : nodeHandle_(nodeHandle)
{
    publisher_ = nodeHandle_.advertise<nav_msgs::Path>("/path",1);
    subscriber_ = nodeHandle_.subscribe("/odom", 2, &BroadcastPath::topicCallback, this);

}

BroadcastPath::~BroadcastPath()
{
}

void BroadcastPath::topicCallback(const nav_msgs::Odometry& msg)
{
    nav_msgs::Path path;
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose;


    pose.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    path.header.frame_id = "odom";
    pose.pose.position = msg.pose.pose.position;
    pose.pose.orientation = msg.pose.pose.orientation;

    path.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
    path.header.frame_id = "base_link";
    path.poses.push_back(pose);

    publisher_.publish(path);

}

} /* namespace */
```